# Requesting a signature via email workflow

Tags: docusignapi, e-signature

I'm a BA trying to understand DocuSign's eSignature feature (specifically, requesting a signature via email *aka* remote signing) as my company are soon to integrate. I'm really struggling to understand the end to end workflow. Is anybody able to A) shed light on this in layman's terms and/or B) point me toward documentation that better explains this than [this documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/quickstart-request-signature-email) does? A step by step breakdown with no assumptions would be so helpful.

I'm particularly cloudy on how the "signing link" works; when/how it is generated and shared with the recipient and how they interact with it.

Thanks.

Comment: @r2evans oops, I think that was a typo :) Thanks

Comment: This question seems not to be related to programming. So instead of StackOverflow you should pose it on a different site, e.g. https://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at these two:
If you are looking for non-developer document - https://www.docusign.com/products/electronic-signature/how-docusign-works
If you are looking to write code - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-request-a-signature-via-email

The idea is this: the signing is contained in something we call an envelope. An envelope represents a transaction. In that transaction you have people (recipients) and documents. You also need to specify how the recipients act on the documents with tabs (signing elements).
After you define all of this (which require you to specify among other things - email address(es) of the signers) you change the status to "sent" to actually send the envelope which means emails will be sent to remote signers.
At that point the DocuSign system automatically generates an email to any recipient that needs to sign that is in the first routing order (lowest number).
These emails will include a link.
That links does indeed expire eventually, but only to be replaced with a new link sent to the same email.
Clicking the link will launch the signing UI where the signer can complete the signing.
when all recipients completed acting on the envelope - the envelope is complete and a final signed/complete PDF is produced.